# Worklight App inside an Android Fragment

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to host a Worklight app inside an Android Fragment?

I have attempted to use the WLWebView inside a Fragments onCreateView

```
WLWebView webView = new WLWebView(getActivity());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///path_to_app.html_file", 60000);
return webView;
```

But it results in a timeout error even though I can see the HTML. It could be the connection to Worklight failing as we are using `WL.Client.connect()`. The error doesn't specify which URL timed out.

I do believe that the WLDroidGap class (which is used as the primary activity) adds a whole lot of extras to the WLWebView to make things work but I don't have access to the source to see what exactly.

The requirement we have is that we want to have a Native app hosting a Worklight app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create CordovaWebViewClient() and CordovaChromeClient() instances and use them with your webView. Check out two init() methods of https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java

```
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
webViewClient.setWebView(webView);
webChromeClient.setWebView(webView);
```

Comment: Looking at the WLDroidGap class it seems like it attaches a whole lot of Worklight stuff to the webview? Is this not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

What is the rationale behind having a native app hosting a Worklight Hybrid app?

The current alternatives are:

1. Native app that uses the [Worklight Native API for Android](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_developing_native_apps.html)
2. Hybrid app that uses [WL.NativePage.show](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_accessing_native_pages_on_mobi.html) to display native screens

More about this in the [Getting Started training modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html), chapters 6 and 7.

Comment: Idan, the rationale is reusing already developed native components (pages) alongside a newly developed Worklight application. Is what Anton mentioned in his answer achiavable? Because it seems to be using the Cordova APIs rather than Worklight, eventhough much of the functionality is the same.

Comment: Well I would go with the "using wl.nativepage" approach then instead of "using a native app with Worklight inside it" which sounds convoluted. You can try what Anton suggests, but IMO it's more work than using Hybrid app to display native pages...

Comment: there's a little more to it unfortunately. There is a custom native navigation and *native* swipe events. I have already considered the other options you're suggesting as I have used them in the past. My question is specifically around whether we can host a Worklight hybrid application within a native application.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for that. It may be possible using Anton's approach but there is no official support for it. We were successful in using Worklight's activity in an Android Background Service and this is somewhat related/the same. I suggest then to refer to Anton's answer and see if you can do something with it.